# Just passing Java generic type through, but still getting not-within-its-bound error

Tags: java, generics

I have this class:

```
public abstract class SuperClass<
   CONE extends ClassOne,
   OBJ,
   VOBJ extends ValidateValue<OBJ>>
```

which I'm trying to extend with this:

```
public class SubClass<CONE,VOBJ>
   extends SuperClass<CONE,Object,VOBJ>  {
```

but am getting these two errors.

```
type parameter CONE is not within its bound
public class SubClass<CONE,VOBJ> extends SuperClass<CONE,Object,VOBJ>  {
type parameter VOBJ is not within its bound
public class SubClass<CONE,VOBJ> extends SuperClass<CONE,Object,VOBJ>  {
```

If I change SubClass to this:

```
public class SubClass
   extends SuperClass<ClassOne,Object,ValidateValue<Object>>  {
```

It compiles fine.

This makes no sense to me, as I'm simply passing CONE and VOBJ up the chain.

I would appreciate some advice. This is puzzling me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type parameters declared in

```
public class SubClass<CONE,VOBJ>
```

ie. `ONE` and `VOBJ` don't have the bounds that `SuperClass` is expecting and therefore can't be used as type arguments for the parent class. It would need to be

```
public class SubClass<CONE extends ClassOne, VOBJ extends ValidateValue<Object>>>
   extends SuperClass<CONE, Object, VOBJ>  {
    ...
}
```

In your declaration that works

```
public class SubClass
   extends SuperClass<ClassOne,Object,ValidateValue<Object>>  {
```

you are passing type arguments that do match the bound. `ClassOne` matches `T extends ClassOne` and `ValidateValue<Object>` matches `T extends ValidateValue<F>` where `F` is `Object`.

Comment: Oh man oh man. I've been away from generics too long. Thank you.